# how to stop text changed texbox from runing contains text code?

Tags: c#

How would I stop text changed from running if statement? because after I type {} the code runs, but if I type any letter or press enter after I type {} the code keeps on making new labels in every letter typed or entered. 
This is for WPF c#

```cs
            private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {            
                if (textBox.Text.Contains("{") && textBox.Text.Contains("}"))
                {             
                    DraggableLabel ag = new DraggableLabel();
                    ag.Name = "A";
                    ag.Content = "you have bracket";    //(i + 1).ToString();
                    ag.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                    ag.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);
                    DesigningCanvas.Children.Add(ag);    

                    ab = ag;    
                }           
            }
```

Comment: You may use a conditional variable (a bool mutex for vars).

Comment: You should not be creating new UI elements in your `TextChanged` handler. [If you explained why you are doing that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) we may be able to help.

Comment: @Olivier I don't think mutex is the way to go , isn't it for stoping multi-threads from accessing same memory? Dour I'm new to coding so I only know this way of doing it. sorry. We all gotta start somewhere. but you could take me in the right direction.

Comment: I need something like changing the argument to only run when contains {} and not run every text changed. but I don't know how to do it. Tried to google no luck.

Comment: The reason it always executes is because once you add `{` to you text box, the text box **always** contains that `{` unless it's actually removed (in short, you are not only viewing the change but the complete text including the change). As such your condition will always return true. If you could explain what your end goal is, `not what you are currently attempting as a solution`, someone may be able to offer some advice.

Comment: I'm trying to create label every {} in the textbox and I'm making a basic code editor

Comment: @0sait05 See `brasProcessed` used by Caius Jard. It is a conditional variable, an int here, not a bool. When a bool, it is like a mutex, conceptually speaking. The int here is like a semaphore. Not between thread or processes, but for method processing.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the comments about avoiding creating UI elements in event handlers, what you need is a system that only activates if there are new `{ }` pairs in the textbox. Perhaps something like:

```
        private int brasProcessed = 0;

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            int countOpenBra = textBox.Text.Count(c => c == '{');
            int countCloseBra = textBox.Text.Count(c => c == '}');

            //if there is a matched pair of {} (equal counts) and more { have appeared than we know we've processed before...
            if (countOpenBra == countCloseBra && countOpenBra > brasProcessed)
            {             
                DraggableLabel ag = new DraggableLabel();
                ag.Name = "A";
                ag.Content = "you have bracket";    //(i + 1).ToString();
                ag.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                ag.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);
                DesigningCanvas.Children.Add(ag);    

                ab = ag;  

                //mark the current count of {} as processed so the code will not fire again until someone adds a new { } pair
                brasProcessed = countOpenBra;  
            }           
        }
```

Now this code will only fire when new pairs of { } are added. Every time you add a { } pair the code will run. It does not cater for deleted. It does not cater for multiples if a large amount of text containing multiple { } is pasted in. It hence likely needs some improvement but as others have noted you didn't tell us what you were trying to do, only that your solution for it was broken, and alas the solution didn't really allow us to infer what you're trying to do

Comment: I'm trying to create label every {} in the textbox and I'm making a basic code editor